# Google Analytic Search and replace according to list

Tags: replace, filter, google-analytics, report, uri

Scenario:

In Google Analytic, I notice that it is possible to replace certain URI parameter to words that you want by using search and replace filter like the following example below.

e.g. www.example.com/abc/product_id=3 -----> www.example.com/abc/product_name=shampoo

Problems:

Currently I've got a list of over 1000 products in my hand, instead of creating 1000 search and replace filter, what would be the most efficient and maintainable way to go solve the problem?

I've done some digging and notice that custom dimension could be the solution, however it would require me to modify the the JS code on the FTP sever which I dont have permission on. What other solutions do I have?

If it is not possible to show it here would there be any kind of tutorial that I could follow through?

Really appreciate for the help, Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but it's certainly more than a comment.

Besides the tedium of writing this out by hand, I can think of two options available to you.

Firstly, you could use the Google Analytics Management API (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/). By constructing a set of commands, you could quickly iterate through your list and create the required 1,000 search and replace filters.

Secondly, if you were to use Google Tag Manager you would be able to create a Custom JavaScript Variable that takes the page path and compares it to your list. This variable could then replace the Page field before the hit data is sent to Google Analytics. This may sound more complicated, but it would allow you to pull your solution out of Google Analytics and into the flexible world of JavaScript.

Comment: Although right now i've no idea how does these two options works, but that actually point me to a totally different directions. 

Thanks for your answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you rewrite the product_id to a product_name once, you will have to maintain that cross reference every day and keep it in sync with what appears on the website -- make sure you have an automated solution or it will quickly get out-of-sync and be more of a mess than before.

An alternative is to do the search-and-replace on the reporting side. 
I know Analytics Edge or Analytics Canvas products could easily do this, or you could just download into Excel or Google Sheets and do a series of lookup formulae.